# Java illegal argument exception on Servlet/3.0

Tags: java, http, servlet-3.0

i noticed that in one site(not mine) there is this exception triggered when i passed some non-valid urlencoded character(something like `%kk` or any couple of letter) in any of the http argument. Does anybody know why there is this behavior? 
The exception is, as the title said :
`Error 500: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`

Comment: IllegalArgumentException seems like a perfectly reasonable response to non-valid query parameters. What else do you want to happen?

Comment: Here on Stack Overflow, you get "400 Bad Request. The URL is invalid": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37588437/java-illegal-argument-exception-on-servlet-3-0%kk

Comment: yes but why? 
for example: foo?bar=hello%ll return an exception. Is this because java see that %ll isn't a valid character?

Comment: Yes. Java (or any other URL decoding library) will produce an error when you give it a URL that cannot be decoded.

Comment: ok nice, i didn't know. Thank you